# ng-mousedown handler attaching to ng-mouseup's event

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use `ng-mousedown` and `ng-mouseup` in concert, however `ng-mousedown` is firing twice and `ng-mouseup` is not firing at all. For example, the following code causes `count` to increment by two instead of going up on press and down on release:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body ng-app>
    <div>
      <div style="background-color: blue; width: 80px;" ng-mousedown="count = count + 1" ng-mouseup="count = count - 1" ng-init="count=0">Click Me</div>
      <div>{{count}}</div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I change the Angular version to 1.1.1 it works as expected. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Angular? I've tested in Chrome and Firefox. It works in Firefox, but not Chrome.

**Update:** After further testing it appears that this may only fail to work in Chrome on Linux 64. So it might be a bug in Chrome.

Comment: I tried your example in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ucbbmbL1/). Seems to work as expected.

Comment: I tried it in jsFiddle and it works as well. So what's different between my full document and jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I loaded the test file into Chrome directly and found it worked as expect. When I compared it to the one loaded via my local webserver, I found the following line injected into my HTML:

```
<div id="__ngBatarangElement" style="display: none;">{"id":1,"time":18.12599998083897,"event":"scope:apply"}</div>
```

That made me suspect the AngularJS tab in dev tools. Sure enough, disabling it "fixed" the page:

[image: Batarang Fail]

What is more disconcerting is the fact that I distinctly remember choosing not to install Batarang due to the nearly universal negative reviews. I guess I will have to add mine to the pile.

**Update:** Found that the issue has been reported https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/issues/205

Comment: Oh gosh, that was an unexpected hurdle. Thanks for posting your solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I would like to note that it didn't help me just to uncheck `Enable` checkbox. After disabling the whole plugin everything started working correctly.