# Unexpected behavior of ng-mousedown used together with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have the following html layout:

```
<label ng-mousedown="mousedownHandler($event)"
       ng-click="clickHandler($event)">
    <input type="checkbox" />
</label>
```

And following methods in the scope:

```
$scope.mousedownHandler = function(e) {
    console.log('mousedown');
};
$scope.clickHandler = function(e) {
    console.log('click');
};
```

This plunker seems to be successful: http://plnkr.co/edit/pb02Zy6MtB322dUE4iUE?p=preview, but I can not reproduce it in my code the same way, though I have some obvious differences like I don't need to process checkbox model value manually in the click handler to change its value.

Also I don't understand why should I put `e.preventDefault()` in the click handler to make this snippet work correctly? And also why not doing this leads to firing `clickHandler` twice?

But the most important thing I collided with is that changing attributes order changes the widget behavior for my case.

When I first put `ng-mousedown` and then `ng-click` I have doubled mousedown event and no click at all, but when I put `ng-click` first and then `ng-mousedown` I have doubled click event and no mousedown. Can it be an AngularJS bug or am I missing something important here?

Comment: The <label> tag will forward the click event to the wrapped checkbox, which causes 2 click events in the end. so the easiest way is to register the ng-click on the checkbox and not on the wrapping label. See http://plnkr.co/edit/CzfBxrj4lzSbo4qyq5Sz?p=preview

Comment: @michael thanks for this advice. It seems I found the root source of this problem - the AngularJS Batarang plugin. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090162/ I solved it by disabling the whole plugin.

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm going to reply by myself finally: it was because of AngularJS Batarang extension for Chrome.

Here is the relative question: [ng-mousedown handler attaching to ng-mouseup's event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090162/). But in my case just disabling extension from the console didn't help me. Later I turned the whole extension off from the settings and the problem was solved.